# How to jasmine test jQuery post ajax properties (e.g url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine, sinon

I have this basic jQuery post to a url which I would like to test it. I do Sinon create server test already, but I'd like to test the url and properties given in the method as well, but I got error because `jQuery.post(url, data).always(callback)` cannot be called on undefined object.

And also what else should I be testing?

Here's my jQuery code.

```
define(['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
    var ProductListingService = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.create = function (sku, quantity, price, callback) {
            var url = '/url';
            var data = { 'sku': sku, 'quantity': quantity, 'price': price };

            jQuery.post(url, data).always(callback);

        };
    };

    return ProductListingService;
});
```

This is my test

```
define(['service/ProductListingService'], function (ProductListingService) {
    describe('ProductListingService', function () {

        var productListingService, server;

        beforeEach(function () {
            productListingService = new ProductListingService();
            server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

        });

        it('posts and call to /url', function () {
            server.respondWith('POST', '/url',
                                [201, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, '']
            );

            var callback = sinon.spy();

            productListingService.create('sku', '1', 10.0, callback);
            server.respond();

            expect(callback.calledOnce).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('posts and call to /url', function () {
            spyOn(jQuery, "post").andCallFake();

            productListingService.create('sku', '1', 10.0, sinon.spy());

            expect(jQuery.post.mostRecentCall.args[0]["url"]).toEqual("/api/listing/create");
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier solution is replacing sinon with Jasmine's ajax.js (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html):

```
define(['service/ProductListingService'], function (ProductListingService) {
    describe('ProductListingService', function () {

        var productListingService;

        beforeEach(function () {
            productListingService = new ProductListingService();
            jasmine.Ajax.install();
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
        });

        it('posts and call to /url', function () {
            var callback = sinon.spy();

            productListingService.create('sku', '1', 10.0, callback);

            var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
            request.response({
                "status": 201,
                "contentType": "application/json",
                "responseText": ""
            });

            expect(request.method).toEqual("POST");
            expect(request.url).toEqual("/url");
            expect(callback.calledOnce).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('posts and call to /url', function () {
            productListingService.create('sku', '1', 10.0, sinon.spy());

            expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toEqual("/api/listing/create");
        });

    });
});
```